# Visual studio test explorer tests are stop executing randomly in the middle of test run

Tags: nunit, xunit, vs-unit-testing-framework, visual-studio-test-runner

I have written some set of integration tests using XUnit with c#. To complete a single test case takes roughly 7 - 8 minutes and that is expected according to the logics that I'm testing. But the problem is when I run all the tests together(or by right clicking a root of a test tree and select "Run") the tests are start executing. But after about 20 - 30 minutes when I check the tests are stopped in the middle(Ex: if there are 10 test cases to be executed, only 3 or 4 of them are completed and then test execution has stopped). There are no errors reported and rest of the test cases are just on not-ran state. Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You are using XUnit but you tagged both nunit and vs-unit-testing-framework, which you are not using. That's just annoying to people who try to follow those tags.

Comment: @Charlie, I think this issue I'm having is not related with xUnit or nUnit. This is an issue with Visual Studio or some setting on the Visual Studio. I tagged this post with some test related tags hoping that testers would have experience this same issue.

Comment: IMO it's more honest to use tags that truly reflect the software you are using. Anything else is bait and switch.